# run Queries and Reporting

Tags: sql, service, sql-update, snapshot

what is the best scenario to run query and build a Report, without lock the live database?
normally all queries and reports are related to Gatedate() -1 (not the live records).

my point of view is: to create  a Database Snapshot.
is there a possibility to update the database-copy (snapshot) through a service?(Night between 00 and 05:00 AM they aren't any live database Transactions)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a report, it would be a SELECT query, which shouldn't create any locks on the database.

If you want to create a database copy or snapshot, you can run a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT, or maybe a backup and restore, or an ETL process to get data from one database to another. You can then query the database copy to run the reports without impacting the live database.

Comment: Thanks, but how to update the database snapshot? tthe goal is to query daily old records(until getdate()-1)?